# How should I initialize a complex instance variable in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, instance-variables

I'm making a class called Matrix. Its instance variables should be its number of rows, number of columns, and a 2D int array representing a matrix (in math). It has methods `getDeterminant()` which gets its determinant, and it should be able to multiply with another matrix.

My question is, in the constructor, how should I initialize it? Should it accept a premade 2D array so that its constructor looks like:

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] matrix;
    public Matrix(int[][] matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        //etc.
    }
}
```

or should it create it inside the constructor so that it looks like

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] matrix;
    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //asks the user to input a matrix
    }
    //methods and the such
}
```

EDIT: 
Or, should I have a method that initializes it like

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] matrix;
    public Matrix() {
        //something else
    }
    public int[][] initializeMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
        //for loop + Scanner nextInt() to ask the user to input matrix
    }
    //methods and the such
}
```

Comment: I would *prefer* the **first** option.

Comment: You could create both, depending on the choice. I wouldn't put the scanner stuff inside the `int, int` constructor. Do that in a usecase then pipe the user input

Comment: The first option is not great, but definitely ok. The second option is terrible and should never be used.

Comment: I see. By the way, @AndrewL. does that mean I would declare a private int[][] and then not initialize it in the constructor but instead somewhere else? Is that okay, not initializing all instance variables in the constructor?

Comment: No, you just do `matrix = new int[rows][columns]`.

Comment: I will never put those kind of `scanner` stuff to such class.  The `Matrix` class should do what it aimed for (representing a Matrix, do arithmetic etc).  For things that is outside its responsibility, have something else to deal with it.  Always keep in mind the single-responsibility principle

Comment: Also, I would make `Matrix` immutable (use `final` keyword, copy the matrix passed into the ctor), but your design requirements should take precedence.

Comment: All three are lousy for different reasons. Your matriх class probably should not be responsible for things like reading user input. The first version which does not copy the array opens you to some potentially nasty bugs - imagine what happens if you create two matrices with the same array, for example.

Comment: Though first approach is closer to the appropriate solution, there are room for improvement: especially you should NOT directly refer the input `int[][]`

Comment: Specifically why all these comments: Constructors should only construct. Having `Scanner` do things inside a constructor violates that best practice. Class should have a single responsibility ("SRP" - single responsibility principle). It should not both read input and be a matrix. Your matrix dimensions are redundantly held in the array lengths, a dangerous implementation detail. Don't just point to a passed-in matrix; if it changes the instance's internal state also changes. Make a defensive copy.

Answer (score 0):

A class should encapsulate its implementation details (in this case the int[][]), so I would use a version with a constructor that only takes the dimensions of the array.

For modifying the matrix, add corresponding setters (e.g. setValue(int x, int y, int value).

As others have stated, doing IO within the matrix class is not an ideal solution(see [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

For initializing the Matrix from user input, you should use a different class.
It should contain logic for retrieving the user input, parsing the user input and handling errors.
One should then use appropriate modifiers of the Matrix class to create the new Matrix instance.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding of your question check below some details regarding constructor,

- Constructor in java is a special type of method that is used to initialize the object.
- Constructor must have no explicit return type
- There are two types of constructors: **1. Default** & **2. Parameterized**

**So it is depends on your requirement to structure proper constructor**

**Like Let's Say**

- If you want to set values to class on time of initialization then you need to take parameterized constructor and pass values for matrix in it.
- Suppose, you want to make user to pass values when class initialize then you need to ask for value in constructor and accordingly you need to structured it.

**So it is always depends on our requirement for how to structure constructor**